# Q: When marking as duplicate, shouldn't the duplicated question be linked?

Tags: discussion, linked-questions

I asked [Why did Obi-Wan..?](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/45665/why-did-obi-wan), and the question was marked as duplicate. This is fine, I realized it may be a duplicate when I asked it, but was unable to find the question so asked myself. I think it would be useful if the duplicated question was linked to the duplicate, because the user obviously was having difficulty finding what they were looking for. And if the people marking it as duplicate are only doing so because they have a vague recollection of seeing something similar and can't find the actual post, then perhaps it shouldn't be marked as duplicate. So I guess my question is if there is a way to require linking, and why there isn't similar behavior currently?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This behavior is already happening.  Go to [the post](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13875/did-obi-wan-ever-become-more-powerful) that yours was marked as a duplicate of.  Scroll down a bit and look at the sidebar.  Under the 'Linked' section, you'll see a link to your 'Why did Obi-Wan..?' question.

Comment: Thanks! There is also a label at the top referencing the other post now, which wasn't there before.